# How do I get Vim (with TComment) to do proper block comments in OCaml?

Tags: comments, indentation

(I have TComment installed, and I'm on NeoVim 0.4.0.)

Given this code, for example:

```
let mem key st =
   let is_matching_key = function
   | Positional _ -> false
   | Flag f -> f.name == key
   in
   (* FIXME: This is slow, but Array.exists isn't available until OCaml 4.03, and I am lazy. *)
   List.exists is_matching_key (Array.to_list st.args)
```

When I select the above code, and hit <kbd>gc</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>, I get:

```
(* let mem key st = *)
(*    let is_matching_key = function *)
(*    | Positional _ -> false *)
(*    | Flag f -> f.name == key *)
(*    in *)
(*    (* FIXME: This is slow, but Array.exists isn't available until OCaml 4.03, and I am lazy. *) *)
(*    List.exists is_matching_key (Array.to_list st.args) *)
(*  *)
```

Instead, I'd like to get something like,

```
(* let mem key st =
   let is_matching_key = function
   | Positional _ -> false
   | Flag f -> f.name == key
   in
   (* FIXME: This is slow, but Array.exists isn't available until OCaml 4.03, and I am lazy. *)
   List.exists is_matching_key (Array.to_list st.args) *)
```

… where there are only comment-delimiters at the beginning and end of the entire text.

How do I achieve this?

---

Additionally — I'd like to get Vim to continue to maintain this indent-style when hitting <kbd>Return</kbd> inside docblocks. If `⁁` is the insertion-point in the following text …

```
(** This is a documentation-block for this function.⁁
```

… I currently get this after hitting <kbd>Return</kbd>

```
(** This is a documentation-block for this function.
 * ⁁
```

(Note the additional asterisk it's adding on each line; also note that the indentation is ‘one off’, not aligning with the `T` in the above line.) I'd like to get this:

```
(** This is a documentation-block for this function.
    ⁁
```

I've tried to pore thru the TComment documentation, but I'm having no luck improving this behaviour.

Comment: I think your question would deserve to be split in two different questions: The first one about how to comment a block of text with TComment (note that asking it directly on the plugin's [issue tracker](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim/issues) could be a good option for you), The second about how to change the comment indentation behavior (and for that I think we might have some duplicates, you can also have a read at [`:h 'cindent'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27cindent%27) and [`:h 'cinoptions'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27cinoptions%27))

Comment: Unfortunately, `'cindent'` isn't turned on in OCaml buffers — I *thought* that behaviour might be from TComment? Maybe it's something else.